# How to get data from address bar in php

Tags: php, html, address-bar

I know the question seems kind of misleading or confusing, but here's what I mean.
If you have a link in HTML, I read that you can do something like this:

```
<a href="index.html?hi=0">
```

The above link is supposed to take you to the same page, but with a new value of hi that is equal to 0. First off, is it true that you can do that? You could also change the value of hi through different links by using the same code as above.

Here's the sort of second part to my question. How can you retrieve that value in php? I saw that you could, but I forgot how. For example, what if the link to the page was index.html?hi=2. How could you retrieve the value of hi in php? Anyways, I hope you can solve my problem and understand it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any PHP tutorial should explain how to access URL parameters.

Comment: your "index.html" must be a php page. So, you better rename index.html as index.php or the server won't execute the `$hi = $_GET['hi']; echo $hi` that @user2860957 wrote previously

Comment: Oh yeah, it already is a php page, I was just using that as an example for the first page. Probably should not have though ;)

Comment: Just realized I also used .html in the second part two. Oops!

Comment: Your acceptance record from solutions given (past questions) is questionable.

Comment: @AgustinMeriles or they can instruct their system to treat `.html` files as php if it supports it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, you are right.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't learn of the answer acceptance feature until a few days ago. Since then, this is the only question I have gotten an acceptable answer on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything after the `?` in a URL is called the Query String, and yes you can call the same page with different data there.

PHP will automatically parse the Query String and place it's values in the superglobal `$_GET` for your convenience, so for instance in `index.php?hi=1` you can read `$_GET['hi']` to get the value of "hi".

Multiple variables can be passed this way, like `index.php?foo=1&bar=2` will deliver `$_GET['foo']` with value `1` and `$_GET['bar']` with value `2`.

You can simply use `&` to separate variables *in most cases*, but to ensure correct formating, use `http_build_query()` to convert an associative array into a valid Query String.